# spring cloud bus - rename rabbitmq queues?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-stream

Is there a way to tell spring bus to rename its rabbitmq queues?  On startup they seem to be just some random values like so:

`springCloudBus.anonymous.4zzIP0z-TH6oIza5mCun7Q`

trying to get spring bus to rename this to a more human readable predictable queue name.  For example:

`testQueue`

or something with knowledge to what service it's holding messages for.

Ive tried adding the following to the application.yml on for bootRun:

```
spring:
   cloud: 
     stream:
       bindings:
         output:
           destination: testQueue
```

with no avail.  Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: anonymous groups are essential for Spring Cloud Bus to work properly.

using a group makes

a) the subscription durable which means that apps will receive all events (including the ones that have been sent while they were not running)

b) using groups means that apps can become competing consumers which means that the events are not broadcast

c) queues are not deleted automatically anymore

The destination you set in `spring-cloud-bus` inbound/outbound channels are the rabbitmq exchanges not the queues.

For `spring-cloud-bus` the **outbound** channel name is `springCloudBusOutput`.

Hence, your configuration needs to be:

`spring:
   cloud: 
     stream:
       bindings:
         springCloudBusOutput:
           destination: testExchange`

Here the destination name **testExchange** is the exchange name not the `queue` name.
To avoid `anonymous` name in the queue, you can set a `group` name for `inbound` channel binding.

`spring:
   cloud: 
     stream:
       bindings:
         springCloudBusInput:
           destination: testExchange
           group: testQueue`

This will make the queue name `testExchange.testQueue`

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Both of them worked like a charm.  Where did you find out about the `springCloudBusInput` property?  I searched for hours only to find `output` as the value.

Comment: You are welcome! The `SpringCloudBusClient` has the message channels defined here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/blob/master/spring-cloud-bus/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bus/SpringCloudBusClient.java#L30

Comment: is there a way to get autodelete and exclusive to this queue as well?

Comment: @britztopher I learnt from one of the project leads that anonymous groups are essential for Spring Cloud Bus to work properly. Here are his inputs: using a group makes
a) the subscription durable which means that apps will receive all events (including the ones that have been sent while they were not running)
b) using groups means that apps can become competing consumers which means that the events are not broadcast
c) queues are not deleted automatically anymore

Comment: thats funny, im using spring cloud config and when our services register with rabbit they are labeled in rabbitmq as exclusive and autodelete automatically.  Thats the only reason im trying to mimic this behavior. Also, we are using a group just not giving it an anonymous name so when debugging the service is easier to lookup as well as letting non spring apps consume the queues to catch update messages.  For example, a node application which we want to grab updates when changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've lately did it like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      rabbit:
        default:
          consumer:
            anonymousGroupPrefix: ${spring.application.name}-${server.port}.
```

It renames all anonymous queues, which is very useful.